# Expressing the solid determined by a triple integral in spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

The problem prompts me to describe the solid determined by the triple integral

$$ \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{3\csc\theta} f(\rho, \theta, \phi) \; \rho^2 \sin\phi \; d\rho \; d\theta \; d\phi $$

I am stuck at figuring out what $ \rho = 3\csc\theta $ (spherical coordinates) represents. In polar coordinates, $ r = \csc\theta $ is the line $ y = 1 $. Would this mean that $ \rho = 3\csc\theta $ is a rectangle of some sort?

Edit:

It has been confirmed that there was an error in the problem. $ \rho = 3\csc\theta $ should be $ \rho = 3\csc\phi $.

The integral is therefore $$ \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{3\csc\phi} f(\rho, \theta, \phi) \; \rho^2 \sin\phi \; d\rho \; d\theta \; d\phi $$

Comment: Is it possible it wasn't $\theta$, but $\phi$ instead?

Comment: We have,  $$\rho=\frac{3}{\sin \theta}$$  So,  $$\rho \sin (\theta)=3$$  $$\rho r \sin (\theta)=3r$$  $$\rho^2 (r\sin (\theta))^2=9r^2$$  $$(x^2+y^2+z^2)x^2=9(x^2+y^2)$$  I don't know what you would call this shape.

Comment: If it is the case that we have $\rho=3 \csc (\phi)$ then $\rho \sin \phi=3$ and thus $r=3$.

Comment: @RafaBudría I'm inclined to agree; however, the problem was written that way as it was assigned to me.